# Trying to get Firefox working with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am playing around with the code below, and the weird thing is that it keeps opening a Chrome browser instead of a Firefox browser.

```
import requests
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from webbot import Browser

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path= r'C:/path_here/geckodriver.exe')

web = Browser()
url = 'https://web_browser'
web.go_to(url)

# 1st validation
web.type('email_address' , into='username')
web.click('Continue')

# password
web.type('passwd' , into='password')
web.click('Next')
```

I got the geckodriver from the link below, and I change the extension from .gz to .exe, which I think is correct, but I'm not totally sure..

```
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
```

Comment: I haven't used webbot before, but how does the `Browser` instance know to use the specified driver here?  I don't see any configuration so maybe it's using the default system browser?

Comment: Why not download xxx.zip and uncompress it? Changing extension won't work definitely.

Comment: When you say you "changed the extension from .gz to .exe" are you saying that you renamed the compressed file, such as 'geckodriver-v0.21.0-arm7hf.tar', to 'geckodriver.exe'?

Comment: Yeah, I accidentally tried to open the 'geckodriver' with notepad, and now the icon seems to be set to notepad permanently.  It must have some kind of extension; it' can't just be 'geckodriver' with no extension.  For instance, Google Chrome uses 'chromedriver.exe'.  That makes sense, and it works fine when I try to use Google Chrome.  I don't see how 'geckodriver' is going to do anything without some kind of conversion...I would think...

Comment: You are on Windows. Therefore you need to download either of the zip files on the releases page (32 or 64 bit depending on your system). Unzip the zip and inside you will find the executable you need. 

What happened is that you downloaded the tar.gz compressed file for other platform. There is no way on earth that is going to work by just renaming the file to .exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
wd = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/Utility/geckodriver.exe", firefox_profile=profile)

url = "https://www.google.com/"
wd.get(url)


# download geckodriver for windows 64-bit from here
# https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will open Chrome browser windows, because:

> "Web automation library for python which is based on the selenium framework"

If you look at the source you can see:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driverpath , chrome_options=options)
```

It means that you open two tabs in these two lines:

```py
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path= r'C:/path_here/geckodriver.exe')

web = Browser()
```

You don't actually need that. May be fixed in this way:

```py
import requests
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from webbot import Browser

web = Browser()
url = 'https://web_site'
web.go_to(url)

# 1st validation
web.type('email' , into='username')
web.click('Continue')

# 2nd validation
web.type('email' , into='username')
web.click('Next')

# password
web.type('pass' , into='password')
web.click('Next')

# Now you are logged in!!
url = 'https://web_page'
web.go_to(url)

# upload CSV Source File:
WebElement = web.driver.find_element_by_class_name('ignore-inline-attach')
web.driver.sendKeys("C:/my_path/test.csv");

# Close browser.
web.close_current_tag()
```

It's not a Chrome issue. See my answer to your previous question!

Regards

Answer (score -2):

You have to add these two references

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
```

After that you can make a test funtion like that
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

```
 public void test()
    {
        IWebDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver();//Open Page
        browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com");//Close Page
        browser.Close();
    }
```

I hope that I could help you

Comment: The question concerns the Python bindings for Selenium, not Java or whatever language this is.

Comment: I think this is Java, or perhaps C#.  I can guarantee that this kind of script won't work in Spyder, or any other Python environment.